# Type reducer initial state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to understand how to correctly type the initial state of my reducer. What I have is.

```
interface TodosState {
  high: ITodo[];
  medium: ITodo[];
  low: ITodo[];
}

const INITIAL_STATE: TodosState = {
  high: [],
  medium: [],
  low: [],
};

const addTodo = (state: TodosState, payload: ITodo) => {
  const { description, id, priority } = payload;
  const updatedState = { ...state };
  state[priority].push();
  return updatedState;
};
```

This way I can't access state[priority] because I get this error:

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'TodosState'.

I've tried.

```
interface TodosState extends Record<string, any> {
  high: ITodo[];
  medium: ITodo[];
  low: ITodo[];
}
```

With this I can push new values, but I can't get autocomplete for array methods so I think this is not right.

```
interface TodosState  {
  [key: string]: ITodo[]
}
```

This also works, but I can't get autocomplete when trying to access for example 'state.high'.

So what's the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is the priority to have the type matching one of the keys in the TodosState

```
type ITodo = {
....
priority: keyof TodosState
}
```

with this in place priority can now only take one of the three values "high" , "medium" and "low"

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po%20rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc%20VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBDIKMjJHq4eDceCCYiofEoADeihKamYmHy11QlE4zAA3FzQMgEexEAB%20fmCQWjMUlaDwCRygVC0WKAC%20wQQnAVArZ-JwDKZLLZoAAvKBOSVuRRefyAOQ8zAu3X6%20CGmgIMhOWA0G2gAAUCpN3nNzNZtmqlHgNjw-PikEMqTNjJjbIAlDaAHx2xQGwTwdwBVXMcOxyAAbQICaTAF0c17iz6jRkAMKJwM0W3VyOZi01-gNiiJ%20TJzWjPPWwucktlyAV%20BViMKeuNqcttsqM1uDxkLyIRPOEHsGjfNxmZjsBjMSD8WDQdSJBggvQiLwAIgAoqsDCIDU%20g-kkOI-uADioC6wgAHKQBIP5BCoADy3xkLsghPlokDHKyZAKK40h4KATinjooxYPoKAIIgMLCFc14SIm0QiAYHA4t0LBsFw3BBCUQA)